# Alize LIA_RAL installation

Tags: linux, ubuntu, machine-learning

I managed to install Alize and now when I try to install LIA_RAL I'm getting errors.

I'm on VM Ubuntu 16.04

The errors ocurre when I hit the ./configure and make

[image]

Comment: I have a small question, once we install Alize and LIA_RAL, we can execute these methods from c++ code? Or how can we do that?

Answer (score 1):

Use the following commands:

```
mkdir alize
cd alize
wget http://mistral.univ-avignon.fr/src/ALIZE_3.0.zip
wget http://mistral.univ-avignon.fr/src/LIA_RAL_3.0.zip
unzip ALIZE_3.0.zip
unzip LIA_RAL_3.0.zip
mv ALIZE_3.0 ALIZE
cd LIA_RAL_3.0
./configure
```

It should work now.

Comment: thanks, but didn't help, I have the same error

Comment: @salama2121 I completely changed the answer. Check it out.

Comment: I managed to fix it I added the absolute path for Alize. ./configure --with-alize=Absolute